# move_uploaded_file() -- file uploaded but not in tmp?

Tags: php, file-upload, tmp

while searching the error, why my file-upload doesn't work I have made a single php-file which outputs me the `$_FILES`-array

```
name:"anerkennung.jpg", type:"image/jpeg", tmp_name:"/tmp/phpMnQVBT", error:0, size:79244
```

when I am lookimg into the tmp/-folder.. the file is **not** there(!)

What could be the problem here? Btw. what else could I try?

I just want to make a simple `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: The file exists for the duration of the script.... You need to move the file `tmp_name` value to a permanent location to be able to view it.

Answer (score 0):

The `tmp` file doesn't exist when the script has finished executing - that's the purpose of the `tmp` folder!

You need to move the file using `move_uploaded_file()` in the PHP script:

```
$temp = $_FILES["tmp_name"];
$newlocation = "./uploads/myfile.jpeg";

if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $newlocation)){
    //File was successfully moved!
}
```

Comment: but when I do a simple `print_r($_FILES);` on the server-side.. without any move_uploaded_file.. the file should be in the tmp-folder.. shouldn't it?

Comment: Only for the duration of the `PHP` script. That's why you need to move the uploaded file in that code because once the script finishes the file will no longer exist!

Comment: Ok I have made a move_uploaded_file() and it says no errror, to.. but the file is not there

Comment: Does the file get moved to the location you are specifying? Change the `$newlocation` variable to a location that you can check!

Comment: I have already tried everything I could imagine.. absolute paths, relative paths.. with / .. wihtout / .. with ./.. ans so on.. when i make a `sleep(30)` in my PHP-Script I can see the file in the tmp-Folder.. but then it is gone .. it is neither copied by copy() nor by move_uploaded_file() .. move_uploaded_file() has it's own error-handling.. that says that everything is ok.. but it isn't :/

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions set for the folder you're copying to?

Comment: Yes.. I set it to 0777 to be sure